# UIView.animateKeyframes jumps to start of next animation instead of transitioning smoothly

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewanimation

I'm trying to create an animation where an object moves from one keypoint to the next smoothly.  As of right now the object does move to the different key points but instead of transitioning to each one as soon as it finishes one animation it automatically jumps to the next keypoint but with no transition animation in between. This is the function I'm using:

```
  func keyframeAnimate () {

    UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: 3, delay: 0, options: [], animations: {

      UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0, relativeDuration: 1.0, animations: {
        let translation = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 150, y: 150)
        self.square.alpha = 0.5
        self.square.transform = translation.rotated(by: CGFloat.pi).scaledBy(x: 2, y: 2)
      })

      UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 1.01, relativeDuration: 1.0, animations: {
        let translation = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 100, y: 400)
        self.square.alpha = 1
        self.square.transform = translation.rotated(by: -CGFloat.pi).scaledBy(x: 1, y: 1)
      })
    })
  }
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Haven't worked with these keyframe animations in awhile. Have you tried setting different options in `animateKeyFrames` method? `UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptionCalculationModeLinear` Looks like it might help. also Idk if your relative start time at 1.01 there will be that .01 sec duration in between start and stop of next animation. Idk if that is detrimental but I would maybe just change it to 1.0 to see the effect.

Comment: oh, ok. Changing the relative start times worked. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah and I just ran your code as is in a playground and it worked for me. Not sure what significance of the start times could be but glad you got it working.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in the relative start and relative duration. As the documentation explains, these parameters should be values between 0 and 1 because these are fractions of the entire `animateKeyframes(withDuration:` **duration**